# Custom Angular 4 Validator depends on dynamic value

Tags: angular, validation, angular4-forms

I have to create a custom validator `validLocation`

`<input [(ngModel)] ="search" (change)="searchLocation" [validLocation] = "location" />`

So when the user enters a value `searchLocation` will get the searched value and set `location` via Ajax.

The problem is how do I track inside the validation directive what value was set in `location`

I tried using @Input `validLocation` and `ngOnChanges` but how do trigger a validate once new data is set which would be set after the promise is resolved.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share more code or add you'r sample to https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly you can pass your promise or observable to your directive and check it's value when it resolve, something like :

```
@Directive({ selector: '[validLocation]' })
export class ValidLocation implements OnInit {

isPromiseDone: boolean;
promise: any;

@Input()
set validLocation(passedValue: any) {
    if (!passedValue) {
        return;
    }

    const isObservable: boolean = passedValue instanceof Observable;
    const isSubscription: boolean = passedValue instanceof Subscription;
    const isPromise: boolean = passedValue instanceof Promise;

    if (isObservable) {
        this.promise = passedValue.toPromise();
    } else if (isSubscription) {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            (passedValue as Subscription).add(resolve);
        });
    } else if (isPromise) {
        this.promise = passedValue;
    }
    this.checkAndInitPromiseHandler();
}

constructor() {}

initPromiseHandler() {
    const promise = this.promise;
    this.isPromiseDone = false;
    const resolveLoadingState = () => {
        this.isPromiseDone = true;
        this.doSomething()
    };
    if (promise.finally) {
        promise.finally(resolveLoadingState);
    } else {
        promise
            .then(resolveLoadingState, resolveLoadingState);
    }
}

checkAndInitPromiseHandler() {
    if (this.promise) {
        this.initPromiseHandler();
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.checkAndInitPromiseHandler();
}

doSomething(){}
}
```